# how to write a JSP page that received data from an XML RESTful web service?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, rest

I have a fair amount of JSP and JSF experience.  Not so much with Javascript and AJAX.

I am writing a simple JSP page that is supposed to post some data to a webservice.  The webservice returns a block of XML and then a list of fields in the JSP page need to get populated with the values in the XML data.

What I've done to get started is write a basic servlet that accepts the JSP post, then in turn posts the data to the web service, parses the XML and puts the data in a form the JSP can see.

But I know this can be done with Javascript and/or AJAX -- I'm just not sure how to get started.

How should I get my JSP form to post data to a RESTful web service and then parse the XML results?

Thanks!
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task has little to do with JSP.

You will need to do some research on **XmlHttpRequest**.  This is a JavaScript object that makes Ajax requests in the browser.  You can create a form, but instead of letting the browser POST the form to the RESTful service, you will need to process it in JavaScript.  The JavaScript should use XmlHttpRequest to POST an object to the service (XML) and then the result is automatically parsed.  You can then use the resulting object and insert those values into your output HTML.  This all happens dynamically in the browser, not on the server.